# Getting elements that have specific attributes by pyquery

Tags: python, pyquery

I have something like this in HTML page:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data1">Value1</span>
        <span data-view-en="test1"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data2">Value2</span>
        <span data-view-en="test2"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data3">Value3</span>
        <span data-view-en="test3"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data4">Value4</span>
        <span data-view-en="test4"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How I can get all elements that have `data-name-en` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

s = '''
<ul>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data1">Value1</span>
        <span data-view-en="test1"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data2">Value2</span>
        <span data-view-en="test2"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data3">Value3</span>
        <span data-view-en="test3"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data4">Value4</span>
        <span data-view-en="test4"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
'''

soup = bs(s, 'xml')
result = [x['data-name-en'] for x in soup('span') if x.has_attr('data-name-en')]

print(result)
```

Comment: tnx dude, but I want use pyquery.

Answer (score 0):

I found correct answer:

```
s = '''
<ul>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data1">Value1</span>
        <span data-view-en="test1"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data2">Value2</span>
        <span data-view-en="test2"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data3">Value3</span>
        <span data-view-en="test3"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-name-en="data4">Value4</span>
        <span data-view-en="test4"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
'''

html = PyQuery(s)
items = html.find('li span[data-name-en]')
```

and for getting attribute value, you need to do this:

```
pq(item).attr("data-name-en")
```